# Return only attribute value from an query expression

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

Hi I need to return only the value of attribute from the code below

```
console.log('starting function');
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
/*var ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB({apiVersion: '2012-08-10'});*/
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});


var newResponse = 

exports.handler = (event, context, abcd) => {
var queryParameters = {
    TableName: 'Ignition1',
    KeyConditionExpression : 'GROUP_EDGE_ID = :Test',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":Test":'Group-EdgeNode'
},

Limit : 1,
ScanIndexForward: false, // Returns the item with the Highest Primary Sort 
Key in this case the TIMESTAMP
/*FilterExpression: TempTag,*/
ProjectionExpression:  "TempTag",
//Select: "SPECIFIC_ATTRIBUTES",
 };


docClient.query(queryParameters, function(err, data){
   if(err){
        abcd(err, null);
        }else{
            abcd(null, data.Items);
        }
```

How ever the result I get is

```
"TempTag": 60
```

I need to return only the attribute value of 60 as string. But am not sure how to get to that stage.

Comment: Where do you see that result (what is abcd)?

Comment: I am using this code as a lambda function in aws. The result i see in the execution result that comes up when i run the code in test.

Comment: abcd is just a variable, the original code was using callback in place of abcd